# Wordpress version for this autocomplete jQuery code

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following code works well but does not work in wordpress please assist:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ac_config = {
        source: "ajax.php",
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#facility_name").val(ui.item.facility_name);
        },
        minLength: 1
    };
    $("#facility_name").autocomplete(ac_config);
});
```

The problem is that the ajax.php is file is not being seen as the source. Can someone help with correctly declaring the source?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you add full path of the `ajax.php` in your code.

If your `ajax.php` file is in theme folder then you can use `get_template_directory_uri()` function to define file path. So this should be your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ac_config = {
        source: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax.php",
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#facility_name").val(ui.item.facility_name);
        },
        minLength: 1
    };
    $("#facility_name").autocomplete(ac_config);
});
```

If your `ajax.php` file is located somewhere else then use path accordingly.